# Pip Install Pyarrow Visual Studio Generator

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmake, pyarrow

When installing the pyarrow module using pip the cmake visual studio generator is automatically set to Visual Studio 14 2015, though Visual Studio 16 2019 is the only version installed.  The generator makes MSBuild search for and older version of the Windows SDK (8.1 vs 10 which is installed) and the build tools (140 vs 160 which is installed).  I have searched for an option to manually set the generator to the correct version but have not found any options. The output is shown below.

```
pip install pyarrow --no-use-pep517 --no-build-isolation
Collecting pyarrow

  -- Running cmake for pyarrow
  C:\VirtualEnvironments\InventoryApplication\Scripts\cmake.exe -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\virtualenvironments\inventoryapplication\scripts\python.exe  -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release C:\Users\!ryan.haunfelder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pi20l00k\pyarrow
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (project):
    Failed to run MSBuild command:

      MSBuild.exe

    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

      Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.2+e481bbf88 for .NET Framework
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Build started 12/6/2019 11:17:05 AM.
      Project "C:\Users\!ryan.haunfelder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pi20l00k\pyarrow\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(379,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2015 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2015 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\!ryan.haunfelder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pi20l00k\pyarrow\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
      Done Building Project "C:\Users\!ryan.haunfelder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pi20l00k\pyarrow\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

      Build FAILED.

      "C:\Users\!ryan.haunfelder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pi20l00k\pyarrow\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
      (PrepareForBuild target) ->
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(379,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2015 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2015 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\!ryan.haunfelder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pi20l00k\pyarrow\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

          0 Warning(s)
          1 Error(s)

      Time Elapsed 00:00:00.31


    Exit code: 1



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/!ryan.haunfelder/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-pi20l00k/pyarrow/build/temp.win-amd64-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  error: command 'C:\\VirtualEnvironments\\InventoryApplication\\Scripts\\cmake.exe' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
  Running setup.py clean for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
```

Comment: I don't have windows myself, but, from the docs (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/python.html#building-on-windows): "Visual Studio 2019 and its build tools are currently not supported."

Comment: Thank you, that appears to be the problem